# easelJS - create a button with an image

Tags: javascript, easeljs, createjs

I'm trying to create a button with an image with easelJS.

I tried to follow the instruction from here : http://createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/ButtonHelper.html
But I didn't know what's wrong with my code.

```
var stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
stage.enableMouseOver();
var data = {
    images: [_imgLoaded],
    frames: { width: 100, height: 50},
    animations: { normal: [0], hover: [1], clicked: [2] }
};
var spriteSheet = new createjs.SpriteSheet(data);
var button = new createjs.Sprite(spriteSheet);
var helper = new createjs.ButtonHelper(button, "normal", "hover", "clicked");

// the code block in this helper.addEventListener (It works with button.addEventListener)
helper.addEventListener("click", handleClickPlayAgain);
button.x = posX;
button.y = posY;
button.gotoAndStop("normal");
stage.update();
```

The _imgLoaded doesn't appear on the canvas, and the code fail here :`helper.addEventListener`

Do you have any idea, how to create a button with an image with easelJS please ?

Thanks

Comment: I'm trying to create something like this : http://btools.eu/demos/canvas_easeljs/button_states/button_states.html but when I tried this code in local, the click doesn't work... I don't understand why.

Comment: What error are you getting on the `helper.addEventListener` line?

Comment: Also please include which version of [tag:easeljs] you are using.

Comment: As your comment notes, you should be adding events to the button instance, not the helper. The helper only manages states for you, as ButtonHelper is not an EventDispatcher.

Comment: Can you show the code that loads the image? If the image is not yet loaded, then it will not display when the stage is updated.

Answer (score 0):

I did it, sorry but I make a mistake earlier in my code, the buttons are working fine as shown in the link (btools.eu).
I was working with multiple canvas, and the click is only caught on the canvas with the higher z-index.
I changed my call on another canvas and it's working fine.

I worked with the latest easeljs lib 0.7.1 available atm.
Thanks for all your answers